# How to get api from database network using database ,username ,password in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm setting up My connection with SAP Service layer one. I have used static API but this time want to connect to API using

```
[
    username: { UserName: 'MySAPUserName', DBCompany: MySAPDBName }, 
    Password: "MySAPPassword"
]
```

I don't know how to setup connection in react native using this basic authentication .

I trie some of the solution but failed to get the response

```
var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + base64.encode('{UserName:'MySAPUserName',DBCompany:MySAPDBName}:MySAPPassword'));
    fetch("https://EEPLhana:50000/b1s/v1/ProjectsService_GetProjectList",{
        headers: headers
    }) 
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: is the host `EEPLhana` accessible from your phone?

Comment: the header string is encoded incorrectly, use `+` to concatenate

Comment: I'm getting network connection failed.

Comment: In postman I received my Result but in react native I'm getting network connection failed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have these variables in scope, since you have only shared a snippet. But assuming these are variables, the string concatenation is wrong. and the structure also seems wrong

```
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + base64.encode('{"UserName":"'+MySAPUserName+'","DBCompany":"'+MySAPDBName+'", "Password":"'+MySAPPassword+'"}'));
```

A better approach would be to create an object and stringify it like below

```
let auth = { Username: MySAPUserName, DBCompany: MySAPDBName, Password: MYSAPPassword };
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + base64.encode(JSON.stringify(auth)));
```